# writing lines into text file with loop

Tags: command-line, scripts

```
echo -n "##### INPUTS? #######"
read -a inputs
```

assume user's input: `polv brmu ankr`

I need to write below line into text file w.r.t. the user's input with loop;

```
stab_site polv brmu ankr
```

"stab_site" is constant string and the others are user's input.

Comment: can you please specify, what you want do achieve with a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a script which prints `stab_site polv brmu ankr` in a file named `filename` if user enters  `polv brmu ankr` in the input.

However I didn't understand what you want to acheive with loop, so I've done nothing about it.

```
echo -n "##### INPUTS? #######"
read  inputs
text="stab_site "
name=filename
touch $name
echo $text$inputs >>$name
```